# Setup Emma Code Coverage for Android

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, code-coverage, emma

I'm following this example [Code Coverage for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6254771/code-coverage-for-android) and I was able to make the ant run the build but it's throwing me this error.

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/user/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:620: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/Documents/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:601: Invalid file: /home/user/android-workspace/appcompat_v7/build.xml
```

And I'm not sure what to do. Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236507/adding-android-library-project-to-an-android-project-prevents-ant-from-building

Comment: Hi @EJK I tried to do an android update lib-project on the appcompat but the ant/build.xml is now throwing null return 1